# return-value about read a socket

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, network-programming

I am learning Unix Network Programming recently. I write some toy codes after learning 5.1~5.3.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define SERV_PORT 9877
#define MAXLINE 4096
#define LISTENQ 1024
void str_echo(int sockfd)
{
    puts("str_echo");
    size_t n;
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    int writebytes;
again:
    while((n == read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        writebytes = write(sockfd, buf, n);
    printf("writebytes=%d n=%d\n", writebytes, (int)n);
    if(n < 0 && errno == EINTR)
        goto again;
    else if(n < 0)
        perror("str_echo"), exit(1);
}


int main()
{
    int listenfd, connfd;
    pid_t childpid;
    socklen_t clilen;
    struct sockaddr_in cliaddr, servaddr;
    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listenfd, LISTENQ);
    for(;;){
        puts("in loop");
        clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &clilen);
        /*char ipa[100];
        printf("ip address=%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &cliaddr.sin_addr, ipa, 50));*/
        if((childpid = fork()) == 0){
            printf("connfd=%d\n",connfd);
            puts("in if");
            close(listenfd);
            str_echo(connfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(connfd);
    }
}
```

when I use telnet to test the code:

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9877
```

I input 'nihao', Output is:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
in loop
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
connfd=4
in if
str_echo
nihao
writebytes=0 n=0
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Please tell me what is wrong with that.
I am tring to add some printf for debugging.
After searching most common reason for read-returning-0 is the client close the connection. but telnet didn't close the connection before read.
Why read returns 0?
How can I modify my codes to fix this problem?
my operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in `str_echo`:

```
while((n == read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
```

`==` is a comparison. You want to do an assignment. Change to:

```
while((n = read(sockfd, buf, MAXLINE)) > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for my howler...